# Fullcalendar Year View other than January to December

Tags: fullcalendar

Does anyone know a way to base a Fullcalendar Year View with a different span of dates?

A typical US school Year is from July 1st thru June 30th of the next year. I would like to display it that way when using a year view. Currently Fullcalendar displays a Jan-Dec calendar year which I can totally understand.

I have tried setting the year in the listYear view, I have tried setting the validRange to

validRange: {
  start: '2019-07-01',
  end: '2020-06-30'
}

John

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried setting the validRange in the settings, in the calendar definition and even in the view listYear...   Doesn't seem to change behavior at all...

Comment: "year" view isn't a standard part of fullCalendar. Are you using some particular 3rd-party plugin? If so it might be helpful to point people in the direction of it, then we understand what is going on.

Comment: listYear is one of the standard views with their List Plugin. Like listDay, listWeek, and listMonth...

@fullcalendar/list
list Offers Lists views:
listYear, listMonth, listWeek, listDay, list (generic)